# On Maven/Gradle, What should I do if jar dependency can't be found?

Tags: firebase, maven, intellij-idea, firebase-realtime-database

Maven/Build Error:

```
Could not find artifact com.google.firebase:firebase-database:jar:20.2.2 in google-maven (https://maven.google.com/)
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-database</artifactId>
    <version>20.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

source:
https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=database#com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2

available listed artifacts: source, aar, pom

there is no jar at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add available  will solve the problem only the flags. You need to convert the package into jar using `maven shade` in order to use it

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-database</artifactId>
      <version>20.2.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

or just delete `firebase-database` from dependencies as the tools is actually existed in `firebase-admin`, which is the primary tool for firebase realtime database, and has the jar ready for the dependency.